# Is "cold minded" a phrase that would be readily understood?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Will it be correct to say "a cold minded person" when describing someone who acts out of pure logic and critical analysis? How would you interpret the meaning of such a description? Is it at all correct i.e. in terms of grammar and syntax?

Comment: Because grammar consists of syntax and morphology, what non-syntactic aspect of its grammar are you concerned with? The morphology is fine.

Comment: "grammatically correct" isn't really a useful concept here. It's ***idiomatic*** to be ***cold-hearted, warm-hearted***, but not ***cold-minded, warm-minded***.

Comment: Syntactically and grammatically? Yes, absolutely correct. But so is ‘Colorless green ideas sleep furiously’.

Comment: 'Will it be correct to say "a cold minded person"?' goes beyond morphology and addresses wording of candidates. Does the candidate compound adjective appear in standard dictionaries, peterrogov?

Comment: thanks for the comments! you are very right of course, what I actually meant is "does it make sense in the given context" but failed to ask properly.

Comment: The accepted answer is of such quality as to be a useful addition to the site’s repository of knowledge. For this reason, even if for no other, the question should stay open.

Comment: For future reference, it would be helpful if you could explain why you think it might not be correct (or acceptable) grammar.       It is common to join an adjective to a noun with which it agrees by means of a hyphen, whether or not that particular fusion has been tried before.  Most people will understand something by it and the difference between their understandings will be relatively small but still significant.  This is not ideal, but the language is not short of words with a significant breadth of possible meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cold-minded (with a hyphen) is used in print, but it evidently hasn't made its way into mainstream dictionaries (based on those I've checked). With regard to frequency, it appears flat in Ngrams compared with *cold-hearted* and *cool-headed*.

[image]

> A **cold-minded** man was never a wit; [*The National Register*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_National_Register/fV0aAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=cold-minded&pg=PA33&printsec=frontcover)
> (1819)

> In other words, only an imaginary, supremely **cold-minded** witness
> could completely avoid anthropomorphizing the bitter winter scene,
> avoid seeing it in human terms. [Robert Pinsky; *The Situation of
> Poetry*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Situation_of_Poetry/yej5DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=cold-minded&pg=PA73&printsec=frontcover) (2020)

> We only had beer to drink, and very little of it at that; but it
> seemed to quickly go to our heads; and by bedtime any **cold-minded**
> person might have judged us seriously drunk. [Samuel Lock; *As Luck
> Would Have It*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/As_Luck_Would_Have_It/eNmFDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=cold-minded%20definition&pg=PT92&printsec=frontcover) (2019)

> The "cynic, satirist, iconoclast," as the jacket describes Mr.
> Bradley, often imagines himself of an "ice-cold" temperament, "calm,
> critical," and the possessor of a **"cold mind,"** as Mr. Bradley
> does, when in reality he poses as a "cynic" et al., and applies
> comforting adjective to himself, to cover his secret misgivings that
> he is, after all, a very Furioso of emotions, struggling vainly with
> hysteria. In spite of his oft-repeated assurances that he is very, very **cool and collected**, this writer fairly seethes in emotionality. [Book review by W.F.P. in *Journal of the American Society
> for Psychical Research*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Journal_of_the_American_Society_for_Psyc/WjQYAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=cold-mind) (1925)

> Thus sin lies in unbelief and expresses itself in an indifference,
> alienation, deviation, and **cold-mindedness** toward the Lord, or in
> open enmity with and rebellion against him. [N. Ludwig et al.;
> *Christian Life and Witness*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Christian_Life_and_Witness/OVmUCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=cold-minded%20cool-headed&pg=PT37&printsec=frontcover) (2010)

Until we see an authoritative definition, the question remains as to whether and how *cold-minded* differs from *cool-headed* and *cold-hearted*:

> Based on the situation, people may think of killing this one innocent
> person in one of two ways—as either “**cold-hearted**” or “**cool-headed.**”  Studies of embodied cognition have revealed that such “cold-warm” expression is not just a metaphor, but temperature perception can affect social judgment (Williams and Bargh, 2008); thus, the present study tested the effect of temperature perception on moral dilemma judgment.
> [H. Nakamura et. al.; "**Cold-hearted** or **cool-headed**: physical coldness
> promotes utilitarian moral judgment"](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2014.01086/full)

Comment: Thank goodness not everything is in dictionaries. It is native speakers who decide if something works or doesn't work.

Comment: @Lambie We do love to mix and match--as they say, not everything is rocket surgery. :-)

Comment: That is a very mixed metaphor, I'll grant you that. :)

Comment: @DjinTonic: Too true. Half of it is brain science! :)

Comment: ...but quite why it's almost always ***cool-headed, hot-headed + cold-hearted, warm-hearted*** and not the other way around isn't exactly clear to me. And although we can be ***open-minded, like-minded, high-minded, narrow-minded,...*** we don't often use metaphoric "temperature" with ***-minded*** forms.

Comment: I do see ***cool-minded*** and ***frozen-minded*** in Google Books. I'll wait for the book by Sven Yargs that sorts this all out.

Comment: I'm very thankful that we have dictionaries to decide (after research and discussion) when enough native speakers understand and use a candidate that it can be considered an acceptable word. A few opinionated fans isn't sufficient (and ELU looks at standard usage).

Comment: This is a great answer thank you so much! A pity I am not allowed to upvote. In as much as I know now that "cold minded" is not exactly a popular and widespread phase, does it make any sense to a native speaker? How easy it is to understand what exactly is meant by using "cold-minded" to describe a person?

Comment: @peterrogov It does make sense. I don't know many native speakers would notice it and think that the author actually meant cool-headed or cold-hearted. I probably would not notice it, or would perhaps only if proofreading or reading very carefully. Having written this answer, I can't "unsee" it now :-) //  "A bomb-disposal job requires a *cold-minded* person" sounds strange; "a cold-minded killer" not so much.

Comment: @DjinTonic thank you so much, I get it now

Comment: 'Cold-minded' could be seen as an analogue of 'cold logic / coldly logical' as well as 'cool-headed', and so, as so rare, is not good to use.

Comment: So, to answer the question directly: yes, the phrase would be perceived as meaningful, but you can**not** assume that it would be understood to have **the** meaning you intended for it ('someone who acts out of pure logic and critical analysis').

Answer (score -1):

Cold hearted carries the additional implication that the act or thought was done regardless of the negative effect that it had on another person. "The decision to recover your small debt from someone whom will now have to live on the street, is cold hearted". Whereas cool headed is more about a decision you made impartially, regardless of your emotional state. "I fell in love with the little cottage, but cool-headiness prevailed and I did not place a bid for it."

Comment: The question was about *cold-minded*, not about the differences between *cold-hearted* and *cool-headed*.